# Como comparar dos input uno tipo datetime y otro datetime-local?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Esta es la comparación, ya que no me deja comparar al parecer por ser dos tipos de `input` diferentes ya que lo hago con dos tipo date y funciona, y no lo hago asi por que en el `input` tipo `datetime` muestro la fecha del sistema y en el otro `input` selecciono la fecha queriendo compararlas que la de ingreso sea menor a la de entrega.

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <div class="">
        <label for="">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="datetime" disabled="true" 
               id="fecha" name="fecha" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s");?>" size="10"/>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="">
        <label style="color: #000">Fecha y Hora de Entrega</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local"  name="fecha_ent" id="fecha_ent" style="" required/>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui los comparo con **JavaScript**, y siempre muestra el mensaje de error:

```js
fecha_ing1 = $('#fecha').val();
fecha_ent = $('#fecha_ent').val();
mensajero = $('#mensajero').val();
solicita = $('#solicita').val();
contacto = $('#contacto').val();
if (fecha_ent == null || fecha_ent.length == 0 || /^\s+$/.test(fecha_ent) || fecha_ent > fecha_ing1) {
  var delay = alertify.get('notifier', 'delay');
  alertify.alert("Error", "Digita la fecha y hora Completa y la real");
  return false
}
```

Comment: aqui los comparo con js, y siempre muestra el mensaje de error
     
      fecha_ing1=$('#fecha').val();
      fecha_ent=$('#fecha_ent').val();
      mensajero=$('#mensajero').val();
      solicita=$('#solicita').val();
      contacto=$('#contacto').val();
     
   
      if (fecha_ent==null || fecha_ent.length==0 || /^\s+$/.test(fecha_ent) || fecha_ent > fecha_ing1) {
         var delay = alertify.get('notifier','delay');
         alertify.alert("Error","Digita la fecha y hora real");
         return false
      }

Answer (score 1):

Intenta conviertiendo ambas fechas al objeto de tipo [`Date` de Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp), para luego compararlas:

```
fecha_ing1 = new Date($('#fecha').val());
fecha_ent = new Date($('#fecha_ent').val());

mensajero = $('#mensajero').val();
solicita = $('#solicita').val();
contacto = $('#contacto').val();
if (fecha_ent == null || fecha_ent.length == 0 || /^\s+$/.test(fecha_ent) || fecha_ent > fecha_ing1) {
  var delay = alertify.get('notifier', 'delay');
  alertify.alert("Error", "Digita la fecha y hora Completa y la real");
  return false
}
```

Comment: hola @levi arista no funciona se salta la validación...

Comment: Intenta esto para ver cual es el error: `if(fecha_ent > fecha_ing1{console.log("Mayor");}`

Comment: nada viejo, no valida, si hay forma de hacer la validación con dos input del mismo tipo pero que el de ingreso me tome la fecha del sistema y la muestre al abrir el formulario seria bueno.. ya que en otro modulo comparo dos input tipo date y me funciona para generar un reporte ..

Comment: pero no te botó algún error o algo?

Comment: perdon que pena, no muestra error, muestra "Mayor"... pero cambio la fecha de entrega a mayor o menor que la de ingreso y muestra igual

Comment: Ok, ahora si haces console.log de ambas fechas, como las esta mostrando?

Comment: veo que muestra el nombre de las variables... no las fechas... allí esta el asunto

Comment: has hecho `console.log(fecha_ing1);` o has hecho `console.log("fecha_ing1");`? XD

Comment: lo paso asi:   if(fecha_ent < fecha_ing1){console.log(fecha_ing1);console.log(fecha_ent);}  ---- pero te cuento que muestra la fecha de ingreso que se toma del sistema la fecha de entrega (fecha_ent) no se esta tomando.. no la muestra

Comment: pero si haces console.log de `$('#fecha_ent').val()`que te bota

Comment: ah ya se, intenta esto en donde declaras la variable que te dije: `fecha_ent = new Date($('#fecha_ent').val().replace(/-/g,"/"));`

Comment: no sucede nada.. pasa al otro input sin tomar las fechas

Comment: el  console.log de $('#fecha_ent').val() que te bota?

Comment: no muestra nada..

Comment: es raro, deberia jalar la fecha que les estas pasando, revisa tu codigo talvez hay algun error de tipeo en tu html

Comment: ok.. voy a revisarlo bien pa ver que pasa y te cuento

Comment: listo, saludos!!